# JavaDoc Override

Tags: java, overriding, javadoc

First to address the possibility of duplicates:

**I am not** asking what Override is, what it means or the @Override **outside of the java doc comment**. That is **I am not** asking

```
/**Some JavaDoc Comment*/
@override
public void methodA(){}
```

what this means. Hopefully I emphasized not well enough. **I am also not** asking **when** to use @Override or **what javadoc is** or **how to do** java doc comments. (Yes I emphasized a lot but I would rather over specify the question than get marked as a duplicate for no reason).

Now to the question:

In the java documentation, the comparator class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-
has the following equals method description:

```
Overrides:
equals in class Object
Parameters:
obj - the reference object with which to compare.
Returns:
true only if the specified object is also a comparator and it imposes the same ordering as this comparator.
See Also:
Object.equals(Object), Object.hashCode()
```

How do I get the Overrides tag in the JavaDoc. When I put @Overrides, it literally types in the description "@Overrides". How do I get that JavaDoc tag like in the Comparator class to show `Overrides: equals in class Object`?

Comment: Does it not just appear because the method overrides another method?

Comment: @AndyTurner it does not. At least on Eclipse for me.

Comment: @AndyTurner and no it does not appear if I add any of my own documentation, so I would need to specify that text, and the how is the question.

Comment: This actually has nothing at all to do with the `@Override` annotation.  The “Overrides:” should appear in generated javadoc regardless.  I have never generated javadoc that didn’t add it automatically.

Comment: @VGR what IDE do you use? If eclipse, will it appear on the tooltip (when you highlight over the method and it shows the java doc equivalent)?

Comment: I don’t use an IDE.  I generally build with Ant, which invokes the JDK’s javadoc tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this [tech note](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-137868.html) (section "Automatic re-use of method comments ", about a third of the way down), the "Overrides" section is automatically generated by the JavaDoc tool if a method overrides another method.

From the aforementioned link:

> You can avoid re-typing doc comments by being aware of how the Javadoc tool duplicates (inherits) comments for methods that override or implement other methods. This occurs in three cases:
>
> When a method in a class overrides a method in a superclass
>   When a method in an interface overrides a method in a superinterface
>   When a method in a class implements a method in an interface
>   In the first two cases, if a method m() overrides another method, The Javadoc tool will generate a subheading "Overrides" in the documentation for m(), with a link to the method it is overriding.
>
> In the third case, if a method m() in a given class implements a method in an interface, the Javadoc tool will generate a subheading "Specified by" in the documentation for m(), with a link to the method it is implementing.
>
> In all three of these cases, if the method m() contains no doc comments or tags, the Javadoc tool will also copy the text of the method it is overriding or implementing to the generated documentation for m(). So if the documentation of the overridden or implemented method is sufficient, you do not need to add documentation for m(). If you add any documentation comment or tag to m(), the "Overrides" or "Specified by" subheading and link will still appear, but no text will be copied.

Comment: I am aware of that. I do need to add documentation comments to the overridden method and the @Overrides subheading and link still appears but as it says (no text will be copied) so I want to write that text myself.